# FFmpeg 'Unable to parse option value "(null)" as sample format'

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

Im trying to process a file and run the following command

```
ffmpeg -i input.webm output.webm
```

I'm doing it with the ffmpeg library from [videoconverter.js](https://bgrins.github.io/videoconverter.js/). I'm trying to understand what is wrong or how I can fix it.

I end up getting this:

```
Worker has received command
Received command: -i input.webm output.webm.  Processing with 268435456 bits.
ffmpeg version 2.2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jun  9 2014 20:24:32 with emcc (Emscripten GCC-like replacement) 1.12.0 (commit 6960d2296299e96d43e694806f5d35799ef8d39c)
  configuration: --cc=emcc --prefix=/Users/bgrinstead/Sites/videoconverter.js/build/ffmpeg/../dist --extra-cflags='-I/Users/bgrinstead/Sites/videoconverter.js/build/ffmpeg/../dist/include -v' --enable-cross-compile --target-os=none --arch=x86_32 --cpu=generic --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-asm --disable-doc --disable-devices --disable-pthreads --disable-w32threads --disable-network --disable-hwaccels --disable-parsers --disable-bsfs --disable-debug --disable-protocols --disable-indevs --disable-outdevs --enable-protocol=file --enable-libvpx --enable-gpl --extra-libs='/Users/bgrinstead/Sites/videoconverter.js/build/ffmpeg/../dist/lib/libx264.a /Users/bgrinstead/Sites/videoconverter.js/build/ffmpeg/../dist/lib/libvpx.a'
  libavutil      52. 66.100 / 52. 66.100
  libavcodec     55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
  libavformat    55. 33.100 / 55. 33.100
  libavdevice    55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
  libavfilter     4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswscale      2.  5.102 /  2.  5.102
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[vp8 @ 0xed8c00] Warning: not compiled with thread support, using thread emulation
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : mono
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'input.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Chrome
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, mono (default)
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p, 640x480, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
[abuffer @ 0xedd670] Unable to parse option value "(null)" as sample format
    Last message repeated 1 times
    Last message repeated 1 times
[abuffer @ 0xedd670] Error setting option sample_fmt to value (null).
[graph 1 input from stream 0:0 @ 0xedd600] Error applying options to the filter.
Error opening filters!
Finished processing (took 673ms)
```

The end result is stopped due to 'Unable to parse option value "(null)" as sample format'. How would I solve this?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard The ordinary build of ffmpeg does not have the issue. The javascript emscripten version does.

Answer (score 2):

Your `ffmpeg` build is using version 2.2.1 which is old and unsupported. 
It is too old to natively support Opus decoding (this version requires libopus to decode Opus). Upgrade to a build derived from the development branch ("git master") or at least use the latest release.

You should also use a modern libvpx if possible as well. Note that with recent FFmpeg you will need to remove `--disable-bsfs` because VP9 is now the default video encoder for Webm and it requires the vp9_superframe bitstream filter (it is automatically applied). Alternatively, you can force VP8 encoding with `-c:v libvpx`.

Consider adding libopus (preferred) or libvorbis support for Webm; otherwise you'll be using the very crappy and experimental FFmpeg native Vorbis encoder.

Comment: Disable-asm and disable-pthreads are needed to build the javascript version. Its an emscripten build. I'll try rebuilding with `--disable-bsfs`. You can see the build script here: https://github.com/bgrins/videoconverter.js/blob/master/build/build_all_codecs.sh. I did try with -c copy, it has the same problem, i think it needs a decoder available to do a remux too.

Comment: @Akshat Answer updated. Your version is too old to natively support Opus decoding.